# WxChoice items slightly overlap in Windows 10

Tags: wxwidgets

I am using wxWidgets 3.1.I am facing trouble with  wxChoice box.The items of choiceBox slightly overlap on Window 10.I am passing the basic paramters to contruct the choicebox with style =0.[image]

Comment: do you see the same problem with any native Windows application?

Comment: Nope..It happens with wxWidget application only

Comment: do you see the same effect in the widgets sample?

Comment: also could you please try with the wxComboBox? Maybe wxChoice is doing some magic there...

Comment: When i ran a sample program on Windows 10 ( used wxChoicebox only) it worked fine for me..

Comment: so what do you do differently from the sample? Are you able to make a sample behave the same way?

Comment: My sample code behaves properly.I matched all the Visual studio properties , everything is complete same.I am not able to figure out the root cause.

Comment: so can you make a sample behave the same way as your program does? Or create a minimal reproducible and compilable sample to see the issue?

Comment: Maybe your application is using a different Windows theme than the sample is?